# error: passing 'const std::vector<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&)

Tags: c++, vector

I am unable to push an element into a vector.

```
void Addvec(const vector<int> &v)
{
    int num{};
    cout<<"Enter the number you want to add";
    cin>>num;
    v.push_back(num);
    cout<<"Added"<<endl;
}
```

What could be the problem with this code?

Comment: You can't push into a `const` vector, remove `const`.

Answer (score 3):

The function:

```
void Addvec(const vector<int> &v)
```

states: I am taking in a reference to a const vector of ints, thus I guarantee I will not modify it.

But later on, you try to push an integer into it, modifying the vector:

```
v.push_back(num);
```

This violates the const guarantee that the function made.

To fix the error, remove the `const` from the argument, or do not modify the vector in the function.

GCC gives the following error:

> error: passing 'const std::vector<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Which is a bit more clear as what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `const`.

The right code is the following:

```
void Addvec(vector<int> &v)
{
    int num{};
    cout<<"Enter the number you want to add";
    cin>>num;
    v.push_back(num);
    cout<<"Added"<<endl;
}
```

In general Constant is something that doesn't change, and in your case you modify the vector in the function.

I leave you a useful link: [const keyword](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/const-keyword.php)